# Function in base class that returns a List of inherited class type

Tags: c#

let's assume i have these three classes

```
class A {

    protected List<T> MakeList<T>() {
        return new List<T>
    }

}

class B : A {

    protected void MyFunction() {
        List<B> = MakeList<B>();
    }

}

class C : A {

    protected void MyFunction() {
        List<C> = MakeList<C>();
    }

}
```

In my application i will never need that the MakeList() function returns a class type different than the caller class.
Is it possible to change the MakeList function in A to allow B and C to call it without specifying the Type? (for example, simply using List = MakeList() - omitting the  when calling the function )

Comment: at some point, you have to tell it what type of list you want.  You can move the generic parameter to the class level, which makes the code look like what you are asking.  But this question is pretty poor.

Comment: i was thinking about something like
List<B> = MakeList<this.GetType()>();
Wich obviously doesn't work. my function 'knows' what type i'm asking for, it's the current class type.
I'm starting to think that reflections are the only way to achieve that behavior, but i don't really want to overkill the problem in thit way, i think i can get along happily declaring the class type 'twice'.

Comment: I would rather think if this should be a correct structure for your classes and maybe consider if generics would make more sense

Comment: @Icepickle yup, you are right, i'm going to use generics as suggested. i was starting to bite my own tail. this is probably the best approach :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your base class generic:

```
class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    protected List<T> MakeList()
    {
        return new List<T>
    }
}

class B : A<B>
{
    protected void MyFunction()
    {
        List<B> x = MakeList();
    }
}

class C : A<C>
{
    protected void MyFunction()
    {
        List<C> x = MakeList();
    }
}
```

Comment: i was hoping for something like List<B> = MakeList<this.GetType()>(); but i guess i can't :)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I did stop for a while to think about my class structure, and yes, this is could probably fit my needs. I was starting to twist the architecture. Using generics in this way i can keep the flow more linear.

Comment: It also ensures compile time type checking which is something you will appreciate in the end :)